# Locus of the fibered product of two affine lines with doubled origin where projections coincide

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

This is an exercise (Exercise III-1) in the book Geometry of Schemes:
**Exercise III-1.** a) Let $Y$ be the line with doubled origin over a field $K$ and let $\varphi_1,\varphi_2:\mathbb{A}_K^1\to Y$ be the two inclusions. Show that the locus where $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ agree (as continuous maps of topological spaces) is not closed.
b) Let $X:=Y\times_K Y$ and let $\varphi,\psi$ be the two projection maps from $X$ to $Y$. Show that the set of points at which $\varphi$ and $\psi$ agree is not closed. Show that the same is true for the set of closed points at which the projections agree.
**My approach.** Exercise a) is not that difficult. The locus is exactly $D(t)\subseteq \mathbb{A}_K^1$, which is open.
b) Since the fibered product $X$ is constructed by gluing affine pieces that cover it. I tried to show that such locus on each affine piece is not closed. As $Y$ is covered by $Y_1\cong \operatorname{Spec}k[x]$ and $Y_2\cong \operatorname{Spec}k[y]$, the product $X$ should be covered by four affine pieces $Y_i\times_K Y_j$ where $i,j=1,2$. Now each $Y_i\times_K Y_j\cong \mathbb{A}_K^2$ and here I encounter the problem:
**Question.** I want to describe those points of $\mathbb{A}_K^2$ such that they are sent to the same prime ideal, i.e. $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathbb{A}_K^2$ such that
$$i_x^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})=i_y^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$$
where $i_x,i_y$ are $k[x],k[y]\hookrightarrow k[x,y]$ corresponding to two morphisms $\mathbb{A}_K^2\to \mathbb{A}_K^1$. Isn't the possible prime only $(0)\subseteq k[x,y]$? In that case, on each affine cover $Y_i\times Y_j$, the locus is the generic point, which is open. Hence the locus on the whole $X$ where $\varphi,\psi$ agree is also not closed. But it gets weird when considering the second minor question: the set of closed points. Since now it is basically empty.
Again, any help is sincerely appreciated!